# How to load a table in ssis which has column in other table?

Tags: ssis

```
how to load table in ssis which has column in other table ?
```

i Have a dim table which has a column Camp_bk belonging to Dim Camp so how should i load the dim table using ssis ?

Comment: At least show us the table structures. What do you mean when you say a table has column in other table?

Comment: in order to load the data into SSIS you will need to have a database connection, and you can use select statement in Query Builder to fetch the output. There are many examples online, just Google. In case you have any issues let us know so that we can help you where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a merge join to link your fact table and your dim table, get the column you need then load the data you want in the result table.

For exemple you have a database with 2 tables "Name" and "Phone_Number" link with keys (pk_name and fk_name):

[image: tables name and phone_number]

1) Do it in a Data Flow task in SSIS

2) Put each table as a source

3) Sort it by keys

4) Merge it, use an inner join or other (depends of the result you want)

5) Then insert your rows in a destination table

[image]